# Combined Column in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio, case-statement

I am having trouble combining separate columns with null values into one.

The example table I have contains values like so

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | 100 | null |
| 55 | null | null |
| null | null | 27 |

I want to write the statement such that I get a column that contains all the values.

| combined |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 55 |
| 27 |

I have tried a few different ways but I am still getting nulls in my combined column.

The latest attempt was :

```
CASE 
WHEN Col A IS NOT NULL THEN Col A
WHEN Col B IS NOT NULL THEN Col B
WHEN Col C IS NOT NULL THEN Col C
END
```

I thought this would work because GDS's page on case statements says it returns the first true value but my result is all nulls.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by incorporating the [`NARY_MAX`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583429) function below, which ensures that NULL values are treated as the numeric literal 0:

```
NARY_MAX(Col A, 0) + NARY_MAX(Col B, 0) + NARY_MAX(Col C, 0)
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/57755cb3-ee35-4035-80c5-e4571bc9284f) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]